# Why do I get a 'Actions must be plain objects' error?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am just learning react-redux and trying to fire a thunk, this is the thunk:

```
const getRepos = dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/reduxjs/repos?sort=updated`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log("thunk: getrepos data=", json);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I hooked up my component to the store:

```
const bla = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      geklikt,
      getRepos
    },
    dispatch
  );

const Container = connect(
  null,
  bla
)(Dumb);
```

When I trigger the getRepos thunk I get:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions.

What could be the issue? I included the middleware? [link to code
sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v6jyp033ll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refactor your application structure, it's all in one file and extremely hard to read.

Things to consider:

- Use a switch statement in your reducers
- Separate components from containers: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0
- Make sure to set initial reducer state: `state={}`, `state=[]` ...etc.
- Simplify the action to either use `.then().catch()` or use `async/await` within a `try/catch` block.

In the meantime, here's a working version: https://codesandbox.io/s/oxwm5m1po5

**actions/index.js**

```
import { GEKLIKT } from "../types";

export const getRepos = () => dispatch =>
  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/reduxjs/repos?sort=updated`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch({ type: GEKLIKT, payload: data }))
    .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));

/*
  export const getRepos = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/reduxjs/repos?sort=updated`)
      const data = await res.json();
      dispatch({ type: GEKLIKT, payload: data }))
    } catch (err) { console.error(err.toString())}
  }
*/
```

**components/App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Dumb from "../containers/Dumb";

export default () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Dumb />
  </div>
);
```

**containers/Dumb.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getRepos } from "../actions";

let Dumb = ({ data, getRepos }) => (
  <div>
    hi there from Dumb
    <button onClick={getRepos}>hier</button>
    <pre>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
);

export default connect(
  state => ({ data: state.data }),
  { getRepos }
)(Dumb);
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { GEKLIKT } from "../types";

const klikReducer = (state = {}, { payload, type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case GEKLIKT:
      return { ...state, data: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default combineReducers({
  data: klikReducer
});
```

**root/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import App from "../components/App";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

**types/index.js**

```
export const GEKLIKT = "GEKILKT";
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./root";
import "./index.css";

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Great answer but quick question: why does actions/index.js start with 'export const getRepos = () => dispatch => ' ? Why is 'export const getRepos = dispatch => ...' not correct?

Comment: It mainly has to do with how actions pass through `thunk`. The action function accepts parameters from where it was called, for example `this.props.action(value)` and receives extra parameters from the thunk middleware function `thunk(this.props.action(value), dispatch, getState)`. In simple terms, it's a function wrapped around another function... therefore, two function declarations. At least, that's my understanding (could be wrong about the structure).

Answer (score 1):

You returned the promise in action. A promise is not a plain object and so the returned action would not be a plain object and hence the error.

Since you're using the thunk middleware your actions can be functions and here's how you'd do it.

```
  const GET_REPOS_REQUEST = "GET_REPOS_REQUEST";
  const GET_REPOS_SUCCESS = "GET_REPOS_SUCCESS";
  const GET_REPOS_ERROR = "GET_REPOS_ERROR";
  export function getRepos() {
      return function action(dispatch) {
        dispatch({type: GET_REPOS})
       const url = `https://api.github.com/users/reduxjs/repos?sort=updated`;
       const request = fetch(url);
       return request.then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log("thunk: getrepos data=", json);
            dispatch({type: GET_REPOS_SUCCESS, json});
        })
       .then(err => {
            dispatch({type: GET_REPOS_ERROR, err});
            console.log(“error”, err);
       });
  };
  }
```

Arrow function way:

```
export getRepos = () =>{
  return action = dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: GET_REPOS})
   const url = `https://api.github.com/users/reduxjs/repos?sort=updated`;
   const request = fetch(url);
   return request.then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log("thunk: getrepos data=", json);
        dispatch({type: GET_REPOS_SUCCESS, json});
    })
   .then(err => {
        console.log(“error”, err);
        dispatch({type: GET_REPOS_ERROR, err});
   });
};}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but your function returns a function not a plain object?

Comment: That's the concept behind `thunk`. To return a function instead of returning an `action` and `type`.